# Ceilometer rest api, only most recent results?

Tags: rest, openstack, ceilometer

I'm trying to fetch a bunch of ceilometer data through rest api. I tried to get list of instances, so I fetch instance list through rest API url:

http://IPADDR:8777/v2/meters/instance

But for a relativly small cloud (10 instances) response json is over 45 mb in size. After further investigation it seems that ceilometer returns data from multiple dates for every instance.

I could filter it through simple query to fetch only entries after certain point, but how to get only the most recent entries for every instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a limit parameter you can pass in: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ceilometer/webapi/v2.html#get--v2-meters-(meter_name)

as a sidenote, you can also ask questions to openstack-dev and openstack-operators mailing lists